# How to make random gamma correction with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I make random gamma correction with TensorFlow?

I was trying to do this:

```
a, b = tf.unstack(tf.random_uniform([2], dtype=tf.float32))
r = tf.image.adjust_gamma(image, gamma=a, gain=b)
```

But I've got this error as a result:

```
File "/venv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 999, in adjust_gamma
    if gamma < 0:
File "/venv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 564, in __bool__
raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `gamma` and `gain` are not `tensor`, but normal python scalar

```
 gamma = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=3, size=[1,])
 gain = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=[1,])
 r = tf.image.adjust_gamma(image, gamma=gamma[0], gain=gain[0])
```